# Urlfetch is not following some redirects

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, urlfetch

I'm experiencing an issue with urlfetch. Seems that  for the URL used in the code, `follow_redirects=True` works only locally.

Here's the code I used for testing:

```
def redirect_test():
    url = 'http://0214.by/job.php?busy=ПОСТОЯННАЯ'
    response = urlfetch.fetch(url, follow_redirects=True)

    if 'location' in response.headers:
        ret = 'redirect ignored. location: %s<br>' % response.headers['location']
        url = urlparse.urljoin(url, response.headers['location'])
        response = urlfetch.fetch(url, follow_redirects=False)
        if 'location' in response.headers:
            ret += 'redirect followed manually and another redirect response received'
        else:
            ret += 'redirect followed manually and no more redirects received'
    else:
        ret = 'redirect followed automatically'

    return ret
```

The problem is that when I'm running this code locally I'm always getting the `"Redirect followed automatically"` message. When deployed on google app engine, the `"Redirect followed manually and no more redirects received"` message is always shown.

The URL returns a redirect to https page.

It makes me think the redirect is followed as expected only when running locally for some reason. I would appreciate any ideas on what this could be caused by.

Comment: What status codes does urlfetch return in each case?

Comment: Locally it returns 200. And when deployed it returns 302

Comment: I can only guess that it's because `urlfetch.fetch` will only follow [five redirects](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.urlfetch#google.appengine.api.urlfetch.fetch), perhaps fetching this url involves more than five in the cloud environment.

Comment: I had this guess too. But the second urlfetch call in the code was added to figure it out. It calls the URL from 'Location' header of the first response and does not follow any other redirects if they appear. And based on the returned value, we can see that no other redirects appear, so there's the only one.